# Does the following identity hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I encountered a claim in the proof a a claim in a paper that seemed to imply/use the following:

> Suppose we have two subgroups $K$ and $H$ of a larger group $G$.  Let $T$ be a *translation* of $K$, which is defined as a subset of $G$ such that every $g \in G$ can be uniquely written as $t k$, for some $t \in T$ and $k \in K$. For example, if $G = \mathbb{Z} / 12 \mathbb{Z}$ and $K = \{0, 2, 4, \cdots, 10\}$, then $T = \{0, 1\}$ is a possible translation of $K$.
>
> Let us also for simplicity define the notation $t K = \{tk ~|~ k \in K\}$.
>
> The claim is then the following: for any translation of $T$ and any subgroup $H \leq G$ which is neither a subset nor a superset of $K$, we have the following:
> $$\sum_{t \in T} |tK \cap H|^2 = |H| \cdot |K \cap H|$$

Is this claim true? It does seem to work out for example with $G, T$ as given above and $H = \{0, 3, 6, 9\}$, but I can't seem to find a proof of this fact or even an intuition as to why this should be true. If it is not true, then are there any other conditions we can impose (maybe I have missed them in reading the paper) so that it is true?

**EDIT:** The paper in question can be found on ArXiv at this [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401083). The question stems from a step in the proof of lemma $4$.

Comment: Could you link the paper?

Comment: It is at this link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020019004000845 Though you may need institutional access to read it. It is in one of the steps to prove lemma 4.

Comment: What you call a “translation” is usually called a “transversal”, or a “complete set of coset representatives”.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Good to know! I’m fairly new to this stuff so I just used the terminology used in the paper. Anyway, does this sound like a remotely reasonable claim?

Comment: Wait... the formula in question looks like $\sum_{t\in T}|tK\cap H|^2 = (|H|/|K\cap H|)|K\cap H|^2/(|K||H|) = |K\cap H|/|K|$. That's different from what you write.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I believe that there is a normalization factor of $1 / (|H| \cdot |K|)$ (correct me if I'm wrong) in each term of the summand, so the claim is really $$\sum_{t \in T} \frac{|tK \cap H|^2}{|K| \cdot |H|} = |K \cap H| / |K|$$

Comment: Hmmm... maybe... I confess I just assumed their bilinear form was just the index, and the notation is foreign enough to me that I don't want to wade through the entire thing...

Comment: Yeah I totally understand, the Quantum Computing notation and conventions are a little hard to parse. Forgive me for speculating, but does you poking around the paper mean that you are suspicious that the claim is true in the general case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct. In order to prove it, we need a lemma first:

I claim that for any $t\in G$ either $tK\cap H$ is empty or $|tK\cap H|=|K\cap H|$. To prove this, let $|K\cap H|=n$ and then let $k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n$ be the distinct members of $K\cap H$. And assume $tK\cap H$ is nonempty, so there is some $y=tk\in tK\cap H$. Then the elements $yk_1,yk_2,\dots yk_n$ must all be distinct. But $y,k_i\in H$, so $yk_i\in H$, and $yk_i=(tk)k_i=t(kk_i)\in tK$. So we have identified $n$ distinct elements of $tK\cap H$, which means that if we let $m=|tK\cap H|$ then $m\geq n$.

Now, let $tk_1,tk_2,\dots,tk_m$ be the distinct elements of $tk\cap H$. But if $tk_1\in H$ then $(tk_1)^{-1}=k_1^{-1}t^{-1}\in H$, and so the elements $(tk_1)^{-1}tk_1,(tk_1)^{-1}tk_2,\dots,(tk_1)^{-1}tk_m$ must all be distinct elements of $H$. But we can simplify those elements down to $k_1^{-1}k_1,k_1^{-1}k_2,\dots,k_1^{-1}k_m$, which clearly must be elements of $K$. So we have identified $m$ distinct elements of $K\cap H$, meaning that $n\geq m$, and therefore $n=m$.

Now, we prove the main result. We know that the cosets $tK,\ t\in T$ are a partition of $G$, and therefore the sets $tK\cap H$ are a partition of $H$. Let $T'=\{t\in T|tK\cap H\neq \varnothing\}$. Then if $|K\cap H|=n$, we have for every $t\in T'$ that $|tK\cap H|=n$. We also know that $|H|=mn$ for some integer $m$, and therefore $|T'|=m$. Finally, we know that restricting $t$ to $T'$ doesn't change the sum $\sum |tK\cap H|^2$, since if $t\not\in T'$ then $|tK\cap H|=0$. Putting it all together:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{t\in T} |tK\cap H|^2&=\sum_{t\in T'} |tK\cap H|^2\\
&=\sum_{t\in\{t_1,t_2,\dots,t_m\}}n^2\\
&=mn^2\\
&=n\cdot(mn)\\
&=|K\cap H|\cdot |H|
\end{align*}

Comment: Is $n$ any integer or is it a specific value?

Comment: @paulinho $n$ can be any integer, but of course when we specify what $K$ and $H$ are, then $n$ becomes a specific value. I edited the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: It seems like the statement "We also know that $|H |= mn$ for some integer $m$" should follow from Lagrange's Theorem and the fact that $K \cap H$ is a subgroup of $H$. Is that right?

Comment: @paulinho true. It also follows from the lemma and the fact that $|tK\cap H|$ is a partition of $H$. Either way, I thought it was easy enough to include without explicit justification.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks so much for the great explanation! Will award the bounty once it allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the same argument as Benjamin's, but I dislike putting group elements in lists.

Let $T'=\{t\in T\mid tK\cap H=\varnothing\}$ as in the other answer.

Not only is $|tK\cap H|$ always either $0$ or $|K\cap H|$, but it's a coset of $K\cap H$. That is, if $s\in tK\cap H$ (i.e. the intersection is nonempty) then $s\in tK$ means $tK=sK$ and $s\in H$ means $H=sH$ so

$$ tK\cap H=sK\cap sH=s(K\cap H). $$

This yields a map $T'\to H/(K\cap H)$. It's actually a one-to-one correspondence.

Since the $tK$s (hence the $tK\cap H$s) are disjoint, this map is one-to-one, and it's also onto since $G/K$ is a partition so every coset of $H/(K\cap H)$ intersects some $tK$ (hence some $tK\cap H$).

This means we have

$$ \sum_{t\in T'} |tK\cap H|^2=\left|\frac{H}{K\cap H}\right||K\cap H|^2 = |H||K\cap H|. $$

Comment: This is great! I was trying to figure out if/how the $tK\cap H$ could be cosets of $K\cap H$, but I actually convinced myself that they weren't cosets because you don't have $tK\cap H=t(K\cap H)$ in general. I completely missed this!